# Cannot invoke method replace() on null object, but string is exists

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have a string, which I put into `vars`. I see value of variable in `Debug`, but get error message when try to call `replace()` method on it.

> Response message: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method replace() on null
>   object

Code:

```
vars.put("name", filename1); //to check value in Debug
String fname = vars.get("name");
fname = fname.replace("C://_private", "D://_private");
```

Comment: show the line that create the exception

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I  added code to question.

Comment: @plaidshirt filename1 is probably `null`, how is it defined?

Comment: @user7294900 : It couldn't be `null`, variable `name` has value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example this code:

```
def filename1 = 'C://_private'
vars.put('name', filename1)
String fname = vars.get('name')
log.info('Before: ' + fname)
fname = fname.replace('C://_private', 'D://_private')
log.info('After: ' + fname)
```

works fine as it evidenced by the following snapshot:

[image]

Most probably your `filename1` variable doesn't have any value, double check the place where you define it and ensure that it's properly assigned.

If the values is coming from a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) - you can see it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination

[image]